# Read & write data into cassandra using apache flink Java API

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-flink, cassandra-2.1

I intend to use apache flink for read/write data into cassandra using flink. I was hoping to use [flink-connector-cassandra](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra), I don't find good documentation/examples for the connector.

Can you please point me to the right way for read and write data from cassandra using Apache Flink. I see only sink example which are purely for write ? Is apache flink meant for reading data too from cassandra similar to apache spark ?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this documentation and code examples](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/cassandra.html)?

Comment: The example talks only about WRITE (insert), I am looking for READ operation as well.

Comment: The linked documentation refers to the streaming API, for which Flink only offers a sink. For the batch(DataSet) API there are Cassandra Input-/Outputformats that you could potentially re-use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question, and this is what I was looking for. I don't know if it is over simplified for what you need, but figured I should show it none the less.

```
ClusterBuilder cb = new ClusterBuilder() {
        @Override
        public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
            return builder.addContactPoint("urlToUse.com").withPort(9042).build();
        }
    };

    CassandraInputFormat<Tuple2<String, String>> cassandraInputFormat = new CassandraInputFormat<>("SELECT * FROM example.cassandraconnectorexample", cb);

    cassandraInputFormat.configure(null);
    cassandraInputFormat.open(null);

    Tuple2<String, String> testOutputTuple = new Tuple2<>();
    cassandraInputFormat.nextRecord(testOutputTuple);

    System.out.println("column1: " + testOutputTuple.f0);
    System.out.println("column2: " + testOutputTuple.f1);
```

The way I figured this out was thanks to finding the code for the "CassandraInputFormat" class and seeing how it worked (http://www.javatips.net/api/flink-master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/batch/connectors/cassandra/CassandraInputFormat.java). I honestly expected it to just be a format and not the full class of reading from Cassandra based on the name, and I have a feeling others might be thinking the same thing.

Comment: Can I write POJO to cassandra that doesn't have   Tuple2<String, String> format instead return its own event type

Comment: Yes, but it requires custom code. I made a version of the Cassandra output formatter that uses a POJO instead of a tuple with only a few modifications to the CassandraOutputFormat code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    ClusterBuilder cb = new ClusterBuilder() {
        @Override
        public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
            return builder.addContactPoint("localhost").withPort(9042).build();
        }
    };

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
    InputFormat inputFormat = new CassandraInputFormat<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Integer>>("SELECT * FROM test.example;", cb);//, TypeInformation.of(Tuple3.class));

    DataStreamSource t = env.createInput(inputFormat,  TupleTypeInfo.of(new TypeHint<Tuple3<Integer, Integer,Integer>>() {}));
    tableEnv.registerDataStream("t1",t);
    Table t2 = tableEnv.sql("select * from t1");

    t2.printSchema();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RichFlatMapFunction` to extend a class

```
class MongoMapper extends RichFlatMapFunction[JsonNode,JsonNode]{
  var userCollection: MongoCollection[Document] = _
  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
// do something here like opening connection
    val client: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:10000")

    userCollection = client.getDatabase("gp_stage").getCollection("users").withReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
    super.open(parameters)
  }
  override def flatMap(event: JsonNode, out: Collector[JsonNode]): Unit = {

// Do something here per record and this function can make use of objects initialized via open
      userCollection.find(Filters.eq("_id", somevalue)).limit(1).first().subscribe(
        (result: Document) => {
//          println(result)
                      },
      (t: Throwable) =>{
        println(t)
      },
        ()=>{
          out.collect(event)
        }
      )
    }


  }

}
```

Basically `open` function executes once per worker and `flatmap` executes it per record. The example is for mongo but can be similarly used for cassandra

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Can you point me to a similar example in java instead of scala ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224423/apache-flink-executing-a-program-which-extends-the-richflatmapfunction-on-the-r

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav

Comment: can you upvote/accept it as answer if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

In your case as I understand the first step of your pipeline is reading data from Cassandra rather than writing a `RichFlatMapFunction` you should write your own `RichSourceFunction`

As a reference you can have a look at simple implementation of [WikipediaEditsSource](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-contrib/flink-connector-wikiedits/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/wikiedits/WikipediaEditsSource.java).