# Flink connecting to Cassandra for read

Tags: scala, flink-streaming, cassandra-2.0

I am getting a stream of events, which needs to be enriched with some additional details. These details needs to be fetched from Cassandra DB and applied to ingress event. I am using DataStream API of Flink to achieve this. Any working example with Scala will be really great help.

Comment: This question duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/43067681/2000823 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42617575/2000823

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read data from Cassandra for processing in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067681/read-data-from-cassandra-for-processing-in-flink)