# When using apache-flink for CEP and have data in Cassandra that I want to use for state, how do I do that?

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink

I don't see Cassandra connector for source in https://flink.apache.org/ecosystem.html . So wondering how can I use data that is stored in Cassandra for state.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read & write data into cassandra using apache flink Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617575/read-write-data-into-cassandra-using-apache-flink-java-api)

Answer (score 1):

one method would be to send data from [Cassandra to Kafka](https://www.smartcat.io/blog/2017/cassandra-to-kafka-data-pipeline-part-1/) and then use [Kafka as the data source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-producer).