# How to load data from Cassandra to Apache Flink DataStream

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Trying to get data from Cassandra using Apache Flink, referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617575/read-write-data-into-cassandra-using-apache-flink-java-api) I can read data, but I don't how to load it into a DataStream object. The following is the code:

```
ClusterBuilder cb = new ClusterBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {
                return builder.addContactPoint("localhost")
                        /*.withCredentials("hduser".trim(), "hadoop".trim())*/
                        .build();
            }
        };
CassandraInputFormat<Tuple2<UUID, String>> cassandraInputFormat = new CassandraInputFormat<Tuple2<UUID, String>>(query, cb);

cassandraInputFormat.configure(null);
cassandraInputFormat.open(null);

Tuple2<UUID, String> testOutputTuple = new Tuple2<>();
ByteArrayOutputStream res = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
res.reset();

while (!cassandraInputFormat.reachedEnd()) {
    cassandraInputFormat.nextRecord(testOutputTuple);
    res.write((testOutputTuple.f0.toString() + "," + testOutputTuple.f1).getBytes());
}
DataStream<byte[]> temp = new DataStream<byte[]>(env, new StreamTransformation<byte[]>(res.toByteArray()));
```

I tried

```
DataStream<byte[]> temp = new DataStream<byte[]>(env, new StreamTransformation<byte[]>(res.toByteArray()));
```

to load data in `res` variable into `DataStream<byte[]>` object, but it's not a correct way. How can I do that? and is my approach of reading cassandra suitable for stream processing?

Comment: When you read data from Cassandra you usually want to just do it as a DataSet. The reason being is that you will pull all the data from the Cassandra table at the start and then will start processing it. Whereas a DataStream is meant more for, well, continuous streams of data. Can you explain the use case for why you want the data to be in a DataStream instead of a DataSet more? It might give better insight as to the best solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

reading data from DB - is a finite task.
You should use a DataSet API, not a DataStream when using CassandraInputFormat.
for example:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Date>> ds = env.createInput(executeQuery(YOUR_QUERY), TupleTypeInfo.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Long, Date>>() {}));

private static CassandraInputFormat<Tuple2<Long, Date>> executeQuery(String YOUR_QUERY) throws IOException {
    return new CassandraInputFormat<>(YOUR_QUERY, new ClusterBuilder() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
            @Override
            protected Cluster buildCluster(com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder builder) {
                return builder.addContactPoints(CASSANDRA_HOST).build();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Creating a DataStream in Flink always starts with the ExecutionEnvironment.***

Instead of:

```
DataStream<byte[]> temp = new DataStream<byte[]>(env, new StreamTransformation<byte[]>(res.toByteArray()));
```

Try:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<UUID, String>> raw = ExecutionEnvironment.createInput(cassandraInputFormat);
```

You can then use a map function to change the datatype to DataStream

---

I have not used the Cassandra connector itself so I don't know if you use that part correctly.